# Is there a graded "grammar list" of English grammar subjects?

Tags: grammar

In some languages like Japanese, there's a tradition of an explicit order of "grammar points" which the students often study in that approximate order. Taking the standard JLPT test, for instance, there's a list of "grammar" one should know for the JLPT N5 (the easiest level), then more advanced "grammar" for JLPT N4, and so on. Here "grammar" is understood broadly: a particular morphological rule is a "grammar point", an often-used adverb that is tricky to get right may be a grammar point, a particular syntactical structure of the sentence is also one, and so on.

I wonder if there are, similarly, useful lists of "grammar" in English that one could use with students to either test or teach against. I think it might be useful especially to get a sense of "what's missing", and in making sure more basic material is covered before more complicated grammar is studied (should a student study the past progressive tense if they don't understand or cannot fluently use the "going to" construction yet?).

Are there such things?

Comment: No,there isn't per se. There are various methods of teaching: http://www.huntesl.com/a-brief-look-at-the-different-esl-teaching-approaches-and-methods/ All of which usually start with easy  things and move on to more difficult ones. But this is not really an English language question.

Comment: There are many possible curricula, but these will vary somewhat by locale and philosophy. Additionally, the way English is taught to children is different from the way it is taught to adults, and to native speakers from ESL/EFL students.

Comment: You may be interested in the U.S. Common Core State Standards (particularly the [English Language Arts Standards](http://www.corestandards.org/ELA-Literacy/)), developed by a consortium of academicians and education authorities, which are intended to establish national standards as to what children at different grade levels are expected to know. The standards are controversial, however, and the implementation has been extremely controversial, for both the political left and the political right.